# Submit an OSX App with helper App and QT Frameworks

Tags: macos, qt, cocoa, helper

I have an app that contains a simple Helper app. Both uses Qt Frameworks.
I have used "macdeployqt" on both apps.

When I try to submit the app to the App store. I get errors "Invalid code signing Entitlements"

Both apps are sandboxed and code signed.

The errors are :

ERROR ITMS-90286: "Invalid code signing Entitlements. Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on Mac OS X. Specifically, value "HELPER-APP-IDENTIFIER" for key "com.apple.application-identifier" in MAINAPP.app/Contents/Helpers/HELPER.APP/Contents/Frameworks/QtCoreFramework/QtCore is not supported. (This value should be a string starting with your TEAMID, followed by a dot '.', followed by the bundle identifier.)

Same error for all the Qt Frameworks  i have included in Helper app.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does "HELPER-APP-IDENTIFIER" come from? Did you specify it somewhere? How did you do the codesigning? You might have to do it manually.

Comment: i have specified it plist file. this is like com.mycompany.appidentifier. I am doing code signing with Xcode by selecting signing option Mac app store. the using distrution provisioning profile.